# Redirecting stdout in win32 does not redirect stdout

Tags: c++, c, printf

I'm trying to redirect stdout so that printf in a windows application will go to a file of my choice.

I'm doing this:

```
outFile = fopen("log.txt", "w");
*stdout = *outFile;
setvbuf(stdout, NULL, _IONBF, 0);
```

but printf still writes to the console (or nowhere on a GUI based win32 application)

I can redirect 'std::cout' by doing this:

```
outFileStr = std::ofstream(outFile);         
std::cout.rdbuf(outFileStr.rdbuf());
```

But printf seems to be doing its own thing. 
Unfortunately, I need to redirect printf as I'm trying to integrate python in to a C++ framework and that appears to rely on printf rather than std::cout.

std::cout' seems to be redirected but not printf.

Comment: It's not so simple in C, but there is the [`freopen`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/freopen) function which can help you.

Comment: Does a GUI based Win32 application even _have_ a stdout?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude thanks dude, I wasn't aware of that function, did the job. 
I've encountered a lot of examples that just overwrote 'stdout' but they didn't work.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit if you redirect std::cout then yes. I do that to multiplex std::cout to a buffer object that writes to OutputDebugString, the console (if available) and other logs. Hopefully now I can do similar tricks with printf based things.

Comment: Slight nitpicking: What you do in C++ isn't really "redirection", but rather you replace the whole buffer that `std::cout` writes to.

Comment: @Luther Okay cool

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I'd say it's not really nitpicking - indeed, it's the core of the issue!

Comment: Ah, I thought freopen_s would allow me to supply and external 'FILE' object and get stdout to write to that but nope, it's just a more secure version that opens a disk based file and fills the given pointer reference. 
Is there another way to get printf to redirect to where I want it to go?

Comment: To write to a different stream than stdout, use `fprintf`.

Comment: It is really not as simple on Win32. See my answer below.

Comment: `*stdout = *outFile;` the standard explicitly allows this to be broken.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Redirecting standard I/O is a bit more involved on Windows due to the lack of a proper interface to map between arbitrary Win32 file handles and higher layer file descriptors/streams.

There are actually three different layers of I/O on Windows:

1. Standard? C I/O streams (these are used by `printf`, `scanf`, ...)
2. POSIX I/O descriptors (these are integers used by `read`, `write`, ...)
3. Win32 API I/O handles (used by `ReadFile`, `WriteFile`, ...)

#### Redirecting C Streams

To redirect C streams you can use [`freopen`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/freopen). For instance, you can redirect C `stdout` using:

```
freopen("log.txt", "w", stdout);
```

This redirection will generally *not redirect I/O done by POSIX or Win32 APIs* (they would still read/write the attached Console, if any). In addition, this redirection will not be inherited by child processes.  (On POSIX-compliant/non-Windows systems, it is typical that the POSIX API is also the system API and the C API is implemented on top of the POSIX API. In these cases, `freopen` is sufficient.)

#### Redirecting POSIX I/O descriptors

To redirect I/O at the POSIX API level, you can use [`dup2`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/dup.html). For example, you can reassign file descriptor `STDOUT_FILENO` to redirect `stdout`, something like:

```
int fd = open("log.txt", O_WRONLY);
dup2(fd, STDOUT_FILENO);
close(fd);
```

Unfortunately on Windows, even redirection at the POSIX API level *does not guarantee redirection neither at the C nor the Win32 API levels*. Whether this will work or not depends on the effort put in the implementation of the C library to map between POSIX file descriptors and Win32 file handles (presuming the C runtime library you are using layered its I/O on top of POSIX to begin with). There is also no guarantee that this redirection will be inherited by spawned children.

#### Redirecting Std I/O On Windows!

To correctly redirect I/O on Windows you have to redirect at the lowest level (i.e., the Win32 API level) and fix the linkage at higher levels as follows:

1. Allocate a new handle by calling [`CreateFile`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-createfilea).
2. Assign that new handle to the desired std I/O device using [`SetStdHandle`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/setstdhandle).
3. Associate that new handle with the corresponding C std file descriptor using [`_open_osfhandle`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/open-osfhandle?view=vs-2017) (returns a file descriptor number).
4. Redirect the returned file descriptor using the `dup2` technique explained above.

Here is a sample snippet to redirect `stdout`:

```
HANDLE new_stdout = CreateFileA("log.txt", ...);
SetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE, new_stdout);
int fd = _open_osfhandle(new_stdout, O_WRONLY|O_TEXT);
dup2(fd, STDOUT_FILENO);
close(fd);
```

---

P.S. If you can do without I/O redirection inside the program, then you can simply use the Console's I/O redirection at the command line using a tiny Batch file:

```
@echo off
start "my_gui_app" "path/to/my_gui_app.exe" 1> "path/to/log.txt"
```

Comment: Much important note here is that the `dup2` must use direct number instead of `_fileno(stdout)` because  the documentation says it can return negative number and it does if a standard handle is already closed (parent proces has called CreateProcess w/o standard handles inheritance). Otherwise all sequenced calls will fail, which means `_close(fd)` will close the handle w/o a duplication!