# WinAPI - How to redirect all stdout of a program and external DLLs to the Win32 standard output handle?

Tags: c++, c, windows, printf

I want to be able to redirect all standard output of a Windows application to the Win32 standard output handle, instead of using a console handle.

For context, the Emacs Win32 FAQ says this:

> Programs that explicitly use a handle to the console (CON or CON:) instead of stdin and stdout cannot be used as subprocesses to Emacs, and they will also not work in shell-mode [...] There is no convenient way for either Emacs or any shell used in shell-mode to redirect the input and output of such processes from the console to input and output pipes. The only workaround is to use a different implementation of the program that does not use the console directly.
>   (https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/efaq-w32/Subprocess-hang.html)

I'm experiencing the issue the FAQ describes: when started from Emacs, the program will run but none of its output is displayed in Emacs' `shell` window until the program exits, as if stdout was buffered and didn't flush while it was running. The same program will output stdout in real-time as expected if run from `cmd.exe` or ConEmu.

What I want to accomplish is making all the output of the program appear in an Emacs shell so I can jump to a compiler error location as soon as it's printed. I'm willing to rewrite the source of the program to accomplish this. I want to know what "different implementation" details are necessary to accomplish this by using "stdin and stdout" instead of "a handle to the console".

From what I understand:

1. There are multiple kinds of I/O in Windows, including the C runtime (`printf`, etc.) and the Win32 layer (`ReadFile`, etc.).
2. I'm assuming "stdin and stdout" refer to `STD_INPUT_HANDLE` and `STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE` which can be modified by `SetStdHandle()`.
3. External DLLs loaded by a program will inherit the C runtime `stdin` and `stdout` pipes, but this happens on program initialization, before any calls to `SetStdHandle()` are called, so there is something else you have to do to redirect their output.

I've tried using this code:

```cpp
#include <windows.h>
#include <cstdlib>

int main()
{
    HANDLE hStdout = CreateFile(L"CONOUT$", GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE,
        NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);
    HANDLE hStdin = CreateFile(L"CONIN$", GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE,
        NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);

    SetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE, hStdout);
    SetStdHandle(STD_ERROR_HANDLE, hStdout);
    SetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE, hStdin);

    std::cout << "Hello, world." << std::endl;
    printf("Hello, world.\n");
    std::cin.get();

    return 0;
}
```

This has the desired effect, but only on usages of `printf` and `std::cout` within the same binary as the redirection code. My program loads an external DLL that uses `printf` and none of its output is redirected.

Also, I don't want to use `AllocConsole()` or similar since that opens a separate window, which does not integrate with the parent process (Emacs). What I want is to redirect all stdout so it shows up within the same terminal/console that is running the program instead of a different window (if that makes sense). Since I don't use `AllocConsole()`, then code like `_open_osfhandle((long)hStdout, O_WRONLY|O_TEXT)` always returns `-1` for some reason, so it seems like I can't use `dup2()` as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1695044/5862977).

*See also:*

- [Redirecting stdout in win32 does not redirect stdout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54094127/redirecting-stdout-in-win32-does-not-redirect-stdout)
- [Can't send buffer to gnuplot under Windows](https://github.com/emacsorphanage/gnuplot/issues/15)

Comment: Not "as if stdout was buffered", it is buffered when isatty() returns 0.  Write to stderr instead or setvbuf() or explicitly fflush().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used the code example I provided above, then called `setvbuf(stdout, NULL, _IONBF, 4096)` to set non-buffered output and got the desired result.